# Can $\frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}=c^n$ have a solution?

Tags: diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

Can $\frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}=c^n$ have a solution for $a,b,c,n\in \mathbb N$, $a^n+b^n\neq a+b$, and $\gcd(a+b,c)=\gcd(a,b)=1$?

I notice that $n$ must be odd for the LHS to be integer. Also, as $\frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}<(a+b)^{n-1}$, it follows that $c<a+b$; but little more progress...

Thanks in advance for your hints and advice!

Comment: "$n$ must be odd for the LHS to be integer". Take $$ \frac{1^2 +1^2}{1+1} = 1^2$$ and it indeed holds that $n>1$ and $\gcd(2,1)=1$.

Comment: @RobertLee well spotted! However, I am looking for non-trivial solutions, where $a^n+b^n\neq a+b$. I thought that with the constraint $n>1$ that was already settled, so I will edit the OP if you don't mind

Comment: How do you conclude that $n$ must be odd? The left hand side is an integer for $(n,a,b)=(2,3,6)$, for example, although this does not yield a solution.

Comment: @Servaes well noted. Again, my fault; I did not include in the OP that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Just edited.

Comment: Certainally when $n=3$ there are other solutions. For example each of the following triples $(a,b,c)$ work
$   (0, -1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (-1, -1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (-1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1), (18, -1,
7), (-1, 18, 7), (-18, 1, 7), (1, -18, 7), (-19, -18, 7), (-19, -1, 7), (18, 19,
7), (19, 1, 7), (1, 19, 7), (-1, -19, 7), (-18, -19, 7), (19, 18, 7), (-17, 36,
13), (17, -36, 13), (36, -17, 13), (-36, 17, 13), (17, 53, 13), (-17, -53, 13),
(36, 53, 13), (-36, -53, 13), (-53, -36, 13), (53, 17, 13), (53, 36, 13), (-53,
-17, 13)$

I'd definitely guess there are infinitely many when $n=3$.

Comment: cont. I'd conjecture there are no nontrivial ones when $n > 3$.

Comment: @MummyTheTurkey thanks very much! There are some triples with some of the variables not belonging to the natural numbers, but others definitely work! Could you share which are the basis of your conjecture?

Comment: @Juan well I only thought about the case when $n$ is odd. In that case the LHS is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. This equation then cuts out a curve in $\mathbb{P}(n,n,n-1)$ (weighted projective space). Solutions should conincide(ish) with rational points on this curve (call it $C_n$). When $n \geq 5$ this curve has genus $\geq 2$, so has only finitely many rational points by Faltings' Theorem. In practice when one searches for points on curves of genus $\geq 2$ with nice enough equations you usually find all the solutions straight away (at least if you use clever enough point searching)

Comment: @Mummy thanks for sharing!

Comment: When $n=3,$ there are infinitely many positive integer solutions as follows.
$(a,b,c)=(p^3-3pq^2+q^3, 3p^2q-3pq^2, p^2-pq+q^2)$ with $p,q$ are arbitrary integers.

Answer (score 0):

For,   $n=2$,     we have:

$a^2+b^2=(a+b)c^2$ -------$(1)$

Above has numerical solution:

$(a,b,c)=(4,28,5)$

Also in eqn(1) if we take:

$a^2+b^2=c^2$,   then the condition needed is:

a+b=1

We take:

$(a,b,c)=[(2mn),(m^2-n^2),(m^2+n^2)]$

Hence the condition is:

$m^2+2mn-n^2=1$

Above has solution at,   $(m,n)=(1,2)$

And we get:

$(a,b,c)=[(4),(-3),(5)]$